# Error connecting to compute engine MongoDB instance from app engine node.js and mongoose

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bitnami

So at this point I am running the app by the command: nodemon server.js, I did not deploy. I created a Bitnami powered compute engine machine that has MongoDB installed, and it works when I log in to it.

From my nodejs App engine I connect like this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:27017/myDB',{user: 'root', pass: 'password', useMongoClient: true});
```

The error I get is:

```
failed to connect to server [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:27017] on first connect
```

I tried ssh-ing into the compute engine and I did the following:

- adding perimision for port 27017:

  `gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-mongodb --allow tcp:27017`

It said it already exist.

- I changed in mongodb.config in bind_ip to 0.0.0.0. Still nothing.

This is very frustating, if you have any idea I would very much apreciate it. As a mention, I do not have a lot of experience with this, so please be explicit.

Comment: Can you validate that the firewall rule allows all source IPs to connect?  Can you validate that you can connect to Mongo from either another compute instance or your local machine?

Comment: @YuriGrinshteyn So, the firewal rules that are listed on the Mongo machine are some defaults, tcp:80, tcp:22 and the ones I created for port 27017. I think this allows all source of IP's but I'm not sure. For the second question, I can ssh into Mongo and operate from bash and when I ping it from the project console it's up. I should mention that I tried bot internal and external ip adress.

Comment: For the second part - I was wondering if you can connect remotely to Mongo, rather than to SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:password@mongodb://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:27017/myDB/SCHEMA_NAME');
```

I hope helped.

Comment: Hmm, this looks different. Before I tried something similar but it looked more like this:

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:password@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:27017/myDB');`

Comment: Just tried it, dosn't work. But thanks for your reply!